# $\min \{t\in[0,T]\,|\,f(t)=0\} $ for some function

Tags: functions, continuity, roots, maxima-minima

Assume $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$ with $f(0)>0$ and as long as $f(t)>0\,(f(t) \neq 0)$, it is continuous at that $t$. Also assume there is a $T>0$ such that $f(T)=0$.

Does $\min \{t\in[0,T]\,|\,f(t)=0\} $ exist?

The set is non-empty because $f(T)=0$. So if I show the above set is closed (and hence compact because it's bounded) then the minimum exists. But how can we show the set is closed? Again If I knew $f$ is always continuous then $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed and everything is done but I don't have the assumption that $f$ is continuous on $[0,T]$. The only assumption I have is that $f\ge 0$ and as long as $f(t)>0$ it is continuous at that $t$. Is the information enough to show the above minimum value exists or there is a counter-example for this question?

I faced this particular question in a much bigger proof that I am doing for a particular problem. So I appreciate any help!

Comment: Yes it does. Prove that the set is a non-empty compact set, and the conclusion will follow.

Comment: @Don I edited the question. That you said is actually what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions as stated are not sufficient.

As a counterexample, let $T > 1$, and let $f$ be given by
$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
1&&\text{if}\;\,t < 1\\[4pt]
-1&&\text{if}\;\,t=1\\[4pt]
0&&\text{if}\;\,t > 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
**Update:**

With your latest edit, the conditions are sufficient.

By the continuity condition, if $t$ is such that $f(t) > 0$, then $f$ is positive in some open interval containing $t$.

It follows that
$$\{t{\,\mid\,}f(t) > 0\}$$
is an open set.

Then assuming $f$ is everywhere nonnegative, it follows that
$$\{t{\,\mid\,}f(t) = 0\}$$
is a closed set.

Then since $f(T)=0$ for some $T > 0$, it follows that
$$\{t\in[0,T]{\,\mid\,}f(t) = 0\}$$
is compact and nonempty, hence has a least element.

Comment: Ahhhh! I should have mentioned $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$. I edited the question again! Does that change anything? I think this kind of counter-examples won't work if I add $f(t) \ge 0$. Sorry I cannot vote up for above counter-example because others may assume problem is solved and don't look at the question.

Comment: Thank you so much quasi

Comment: Just to make it more accurate you have shown that 
$$\{t \in (0,T]{\,\mid\,}f(t) > 0\}$$
is an open set and therefore $$\{t \in (0,T]{\,\mid\,}f(t) = 0\}$$ has a minimum. Correct? Because the set $$\{t \in [0,T]{\,\mid\,}f(t) > 0\}$$ is not open it's half-open as it's closed from the left side which is zero. But what you have shown is totally fine and that's what I need.

Comment: @moonlight: I was assuming $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. If you're assuming $f$ is only defined for $t\ge 0$, then just extend $f$ by defining $f(t)=f(0)$ for all $t < 0$. Once that's done, my argument applies without modifications.